# Xamarin overlapping problem Stacklayout, bindable layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, stacklayout

currently Im using a Stacklayout with a BindingLayout like this:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MessstelleGeraete}" >
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
                <---- some more stuff in here ---->
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="-8,20,0,-20">
                    <BoxView Color="#0056AD" HeightRequest="2" WidthRequest="8" />
                    <BoxView Color="#0056AD" WidthRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    <BoxView Color="#0056AD" HeightRequest="2" WidthRequest="8" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid                      
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout
```

If for example we have 5 items in "MessstelleGeraete" then whe have a Stacklayout with 5 Stacklayouts in it. Inside of the 5 Stacklayouts there is 2 more Stacklayouts. The first contains some laybels and entries the second one contains 3 boxviews that look like "[". The "[" is as long as the entire Grid. When I shift it down with the margin its supposed to overlap onto the next (of our 5) stacklayouts. The Problem here is that the z-index inside a stacklayout is determined by the order of the child elements. Which means element 2 will overlap element 1 but I need it the other way around.

[image]
Left: "[" is cut off cuz Stacklayout 2/5 overlaps Stacklayout 1/5

How can I fix that? Can I use a RelativeLayout? If yes how?

Comment: I would make the outermost layout a Grid. Then dedicate column 0 for use by that bracket. Read about RowSpan and ColumnSpan - you can have items that cover more than one cell. Or use AbsoluteLayout or RelativeLayout. As the outermost layout. Instead of Stacklayout. Then within that, have grids, stacklayouts, whatever you need for different pieces.

Comment: When I use Grid or RelativeLayout the Stacklayouts are not among themselves. They are all on the same position so I can only see one...

Comment: I found another solution. Im drawing the missing part of the "[" in the lower stacklayout and shift it up.

Comment: If you use grid, then you have to read how to use row, column, rowspan, columnspan. To control what goes where. That is worth learning. But whatever works for you.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I know how to use a Grid. I just dont know how to use a Grid with BindableLayout. I thought if I used a Grid with bindable layout all the items from my itemsource are turned into seperate rows but instead all of them are in one row.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were using BindableLayout. That won’t work right with Grid.